# Mean of a list of 3D arrays in R

Tags: r, list

How can I calculate the means of arrays stored in a list in R? The result should be an array of the same size containing the means... For example:

```
a1 <- array(runif(100), dim=c(4, 5, 5))
a2 <- array(runif(100), dim=c(4, 5, 5))
a3 <- array(runif(100), dim=c(4, 5, 5))
a4 <- array(runif(100), dim=c(4, 5, 5))
a5 <- array(runif(100), dim=c(4, 5, 5))

l <- list(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)

[...]
```

should result in an array of dimension 4, 5, 5 containing the means.

I can do it for a list of matrices with:

```
apply(simplify2array(myList), 1:2, mean)
```

but it doesn't work for my purpose...

Thanks for any clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be we can use `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`+`, l)/length(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first transform you list of arrays into a 4D array and then use `apply`:

```
a <- array(unlist(l), dim = c(dim(l[[1]]), length(l)))
apply(a, 1:3, mean)
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative!